# Ext JS add container to container

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, containers

I am having difficulties with very strange problem. My Dynamically created container doesn't get drawn into an exsisting one.

```
var patientContainer = new Ext.container.Container(id:'patientContainer'+ rec.data.patientId, style: {height: '500px', width:'500px',
                                                   borderColor:'#000000', borderStyle:'solid',
                                                   borderWidth:'1px'}});
```

//exsisting container

```
cont.add(patientContainer);
cont.doLayout();
```

The value fr container id is present. I have also checked there is nothing wrong with the exsisting container `cont`
Am I missing something?

UPDATE: using this code changes nothing

```
      var patientContainer = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
                        id:'patientContainer'+ rec.data.patientId,
                            width:400,
                            height:400,                                    
                               style: {
                                borderColor:'#000000',
                                borderStyle:'solid',
                            borderWidth:'1px'
                                    }

                    });
```

UPDATE: Below is a screenshot of the console output. First one is the nely created container and the second one is the exsisting one [image]

Comment: Post a full example, isolated snippets of code where you don't even show the container aren't useful.

Comment: I cannot even make a fiddle: Stuck here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2t6

Comment: Because the code has syntax errors in it...

Comment: Sorry but I don't see any!

Comment: Take the time to format your code properly, it will become immediately obvious. Or just drop that code into any page.

Answer (score 1):

ExtJS Configurations are passed as object, not as parameters.

```
var patientContainer = new Ext.container.Container({
    id:'patientContainer'+ rec.data.patientId,
    height: '500px',
    width:'500px',
    style: {
        borderColor:'#000000',
        borderStyle:'solid',
        borderWidth:'1px'
    }
});
```

Notice the additional { at the beginning and end. Also it's recommend to use `Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', { ... });` because it takes care of class loading, which new key word doesn't.

Comment: Usually you shouldn't put height and width into the style, but as configuration of the container itself, because most containers do calculate the height and width dynamically and set thus override the element styles. Though a dynamic layout like `fit` is more suitable for containers, so they take the size of it's content (or it's parent when parent uses fit)

Comment: Sorry but still nothing!